# What is the fastest way to find the index of a number of sorted dates in a super set of sorted dates?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, binary-search

Please note that I am passing sorted dates for both, the super set as well as search set.

Currently I am using:

```
    left = np.searchsorted(super_set_dates, search_dates, 'left')
    right = np.searchsorted(super_set_dates, search_dates, 'right') - 1
    matches = left[left == right]
```

This is quite fast and will yield the right indexes. However, I am not sure if this is the fastest way in python. Especially given that `searchsorted()` only requires the `super_set` to be sorted - if it would take advantage of the fact that `search_dates` is also sorted, this could be done much quicker. So maybe there is a function or parameter I don't know, or maybe there is a completely different (and faster) way of achieving this?

Your answers are much appreciated

Comment: A little more context would be helpful-- what's np?  Using numpy?  imports?

Comment: Thank you ali_m. I see you as the original author of the answer that you linked. I replicated your cython code in an attempt to get the 4x speed increase, but I get almost no difference in speed. Both, your DoubleSorted implementation, as well as searchsorted have very similar speeds. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you see Jaime's comment on that question? If you're using numpy v1.9 or newer, there are already built-in optimizations to `np.searchsorted`  that make it faster in cases where the search values are also sorted ([this is the relevant PR](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/4244/files)).

Comment: interesting, i did not see that. Thank you ali_m.